# Contar letra e pegar iniciais do nome

Tags: c, c++, string, condição

O programa não imprime a primeira letra de cada nome.

```
nome[i]=nome[i+1];
```

Preciso fazer um programa que entre com o nome da pessoa, diga quantas letras `A` tem o nome dessa pessoa e diga a primeira letra dos nomes delas, por exemplo: Joao vinicios, o programa vai me mostrar J.V.

Isto foi oque eu fiz até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char nome[99];
    int soma,i;

    printf("Digite o nome completo:\n");
    gets(nome);

    soma=0;
    for(i=0;nome[i] != 0; i++) //For para mostrar quantos a tem o nome da pessoa
    {
        if(nome[i]=='a')
        {
            soma=soma+1;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; nome[i]!=0; i++) // For para pegar a primeira letra de cada nome da pessoa 
    {
        if(nome[i] == ' ')
        {
            soma=so
            nome[i]=nome[i+1];
            printf("%s\n",nome[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Seu nome tem %d letras 'A'" ,soma); // imprimi na tela quantos A tem o nome da pessoa

    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Você precisa informar qual é o seu problema específico.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Tem vários problemas aí. Primeiro eu eliminei o `conio` que não é recomendado usar. E simplifiquei o código.

Não precisa de dois laços, você só tem que percorrer todo o texto a analisar caractere por caractere. Pode fazer as duas análises dentro dele.

Pelo que entendi basta imprimir as iniciais, então é mais simples do que estava tentando fazer. Só precisa corrigir a condição que considera uma inicial, porque é ele que determina se começou outra palavra.

Considerei a letra maiúscula ou minúscula.

Tem outros critérios que podem dar problema no que é inicial. Mostrei um deles que é a palavra que não é considerada parte do nome (`da`), mas poderia ter números e símbolos que causariam problema.

Obviamente que só interessa se for uma letra. Se for pode aceitá-la como inicial se for o primeiro caractere sendo analisado ou se o anterior for um espaço.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char nome[99];
    printf("Digite o nome completo:\n");
    fgets(nome, 98, stdin);
    int qtdA = 0;
    for (int i = 0; nome[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (nome[i] == 'a' || nome[i] == 'A') qtdA++;
        if (nome[i] != ' ' && (i == 0 || nome[i - 1] == ' ')) printf("%c.", nome[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSeu nome tem %d letras 'A'" , qtdA);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fjA2Wv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aysdxvqd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/GetAcronym.c).

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas:

Ao invés de `nome[i]!=0` você tem que fazer `nome[i]!='\0'`. No primeiro caso você ta comparando um `char` com um número inteiro.

Depois, você faz:

```
soma=so
```

O que não faz sentido, nem do ponto de vista da linguagem (`so` não foi definida, além de não ter o `;` no fim da linha), como não é necessário para o problema, já que `soma` só conta o número de A.

Depois você faz `nome[i]=nome[i+1]`, não é necessário, considere que depois de um espaço é a primeira letra do nome, basta verificar se o próximo carácter existe e imprimi-lo.

```
for(i=0; nome[i+1]!='\0'; i++){
    if(nome[i]=' ' && nome[i+1]!='\0')
        printf("%c\t", nome[i+1]);
}
```

Note que o loop deve verificar se o carácter em `i+1` que é o fim da string, já que você acessa o elemento `i+1` dentro do loop.

Também note que com o loop estruturado desta maneira a primeira inicial é ignorada, já que você só verifica a inicial depois de um espaço, para isso basta inserir um if:

```
for(i=0; nome[i+1]!='\0'; i++){
    if(i==0) printf("%c\t", nome[i]); //Imprime a primeira inicial
    if(nome[i]=' ' && nome[i+1]!='\0')
        printf("%c\t", nome[i+1]); //Imprime as outras iniciais
}
```

Comment: esse soma=so foi um erro de digitação eu ja tirei ele, vou tentar aqui vlw